# Query in multiple codes to the same Product

Tags: postgresql-9.5

I have the following table:

```
cod_1    Cod_2   Prod
 10        33      A
 2         78      B
 5        105      A
 7         34      D
 3        Null     D
```

What I need to query:

How many cod_1 and Cod_2  the produt A has:

**result:**

`A has cod_1 = 10 and 5 ; A has code_2 = 33 and 105`

`D has cod_1 7 and 3;`

So, the query needs to show when a Product has more than one cod_1 and cod_2

I am not exp'ed in postgresql so I have no clue where to start.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your table structure and examples, following query can achieve your requirement,

```
SELECT 
    PROD,
    STRING_AGG(COD_1, ', ') AS COD_1,
    STRING_AGG(COD_2, ', ') AS COD_2
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE PROD = 'A'
GROUP BY PROD
```

Output

```
PROD    COD_1     COD_2
A       10, 5     33, 105
```

*Note: All my column names are `block capital`, you might need to change that.*